# Code given in flink documentation does not compile

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-flink

I am very new to flink and was trying some code given in flink documnetation.

Code in flink documentation:

```
public class WordWithCount {

    public String word;
    public long count;

    public WordWithCount() {}

    public WordWithCount(String word, int count) {
        this.word = word;
        this.count = count;
    }
}

DataStream<Tuple2<String, Long>> wordCounts = env.fromElements(
    new WordWithCount("hello", 1),
    new WordWithCount("world", 2));

wordCounts.keyBy("word"); // key by field expression "word"
```

But I am getting Type mismatch error at

```
DataStream<Tuple2<String, Long>> wicstream = sev.fromElements(new WordwithCount("Hello",1), new WordwithCount("hello",1));
```

Error message:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from DataStreamSource<WordwithCount> to DataStream<Tuple2<String,Long>>
```

Please help me to understand my mistake.

Answer (score 3):

The `DataStream` should be of the type X, the same type of objects you provide to `fromElements()` method. You provide `WordwithCount` as argument, so the type of `DataStream` should be `WordwithCount`.

Your code should look like:

```
DataStream<WordwithCount> wicstream = sev.fromElements(new WordwithCount("Hello",1), new WordwithCount("hello",1));
```

Comment: Correct!!  but                                                                                                The code I mentioned is in flink documnetation, do you suggest that the code in  documentaion is wrong?  I picked this code from https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.0/apis/common/index.html                                                                         Section: POJOs

Comment: Ohh now I see.Edit your main post with link. Yeah the example is wrong I think. You can try to post to the user list, devs generally respond very fast.

Comment: @AnkitJindal I have created pull request with the fix. Gave you a credit for spotting :)